# How can I disable emacs dialogue 'File XXX is really big, really wants to open it?'

Tags: emacs

how can I disable this dialogue 'File XXX is really big, really wants to open it?' whenever I open a big file?

Thank you.

Comment: See also [How do I stop emacs from asking me if I want to load a large file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108259/how-do-i-stop-emacs-from-asking-me-if-i-want-to-load-a-large-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the following in your .emacs file:

`(setq large-file-warning-threshold nil)`